# Convert seconds to Datetime, without dropping the microsecond precision, using pandas to_datetime

Tags: pandas, python-datetime

I'm trying to convert an array of seconds-since-epoch values, including microsecond precision, to Datetime format using pandas to_datetime as shown below:

```
x = 1487187300.038075
time = pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s')
```

This successfully converts to a Timestamp, but the microsecond precision is dropped (or at least not visible), producing:

```
Timestamp('2017-02-15 19:35:00')
```

Any advice on how to convert without losing the precision?  None of my searches so far turn up examples where the OP cared to maintain the microsecond precision.

Comment: try `print(time.microsecond)`

Comment: Returns zero! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  `0.19.2` preserves the microseconds in my testing of your example.

Comment: Looks like I'm running 0.18.1

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade until the company approves Anaconda 4.3, but it looks like that will bring pandas 0.19.2 with it.

Answer (score 4):

I think I've found the root cause, and a temporary workaround.  There was an issue fixed in pandas 0.19.1 in which floats were being truncated.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13834

The workaround is to use the "errors='coerce'" arguement:

```
x = 1487187300.038075
time = pd.to_datetime(x, unit='s', errors='coerce')

time
Out[43]: 
Timestamp('2017-02-15 19:35:00.038075')
```

I'm not smart on what else might be affected by that 'errors' argument, but I think it solves my problem.